# Insert BLOB in to database using mysql

Tags: java, mysql

guys i am trying to insert blob in to my DB using mysql ... here is my query

```
insert into myTable (id, image_blob) values (@id,load_file('C:/projects/myProject/src/main/resources/files/file.zip'));
```

but it return null ... any help what i made wrong ??

Comment: Without having any information on what `myTable` and everything else in there is it is not really any realistic way to provide an answer. Please expand your question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we are glad to help you out.

Comment: try once, keep your file in D drive **D:/projects/myProject/src/main/resources/files/file.zip**

Comment: @SandipND it didnt work, it returns null

Comment: what are you using workbench or mysql heidi?

Comment: yes, i am using workbench

Comment: Check that your mysql user has been granted the FILE privilege and that there are sufficient permissions set on the folder that mysql is trying to read the image from